# How can i get the actual results from this code

Tags: javascript

When i `console.log( getSpecificMonitorNews(url) );` i get the actual results.
But when i use  `return await getSpecificMonitorNews(url);`, the first results are overwritten.

```js
let newsContents = {
  title: "",
  imageSrc: "",
};

async function getSpecificMonitorNews(url) {
  let monitorBaseUrl = "https://www.monitor.co.ug";

  url = monitorBaseUrl + url;
  console.log(url)
  const data = await fetchPage(url);

  let $ = cheerio.load(data);

  newsContents.title = $(".title-medium").text();
  newsContents.imageSrc = monitorBaseUrl + $(".lazy-img-container img").attr("src");

  return newsContents;
}

async function getMonitorNews(urlNews) {
  return await Promise.all(
    urlNews.map(async (url) => {
     return await getSpecificMonitorNews(url);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a problem in your `getSpecificMonitorNews` function. Please post its code. `getMonitorNews` is fine (although it could be simplified a bit)

Comment: First results?? Are you calling this function more than once perhaps? I don't think you've shown us the whole scenario. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. You can [edit] the question to update us. Thanks.

Comment: `newsContents` is a global variable so its value changes. You're returning a reference to that global object, not a copied version (and there's no need to copy it if you just bring it inside the function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newsContents` is a global variable so its value changes. You're returning a reference to that global object, not a copied version (and there's no need to copy it if you just bring it inside the function).

So you can either move `newsContents` inside the function if you don't need it elsewhere:

```js
async function getSpecificMonitorNews(url) {
  let newsContents = {
    title: "",
    imageSrc: "",
    contents: "",
    date: "",
  };
  // rest of code
}
// rest of code
```

Or make a copy of the `newsContents` variable

```js
// rest of code
async function getSpecificMonitorNews(url) {
  // rest of code
  return { ...newsContents };
}
// rest of code
```

Or just create a new object on the fly:

```js
async function getSpecificMonitorNews(url) {
  // rest of code
  return {
    title: $(".title-medium").text(),
    imageSrc: monitorBaseUrl + $(".lazy-img-container img").attr("src"),
    contents: $(".paragraph-wrapper > p").text(),
    date: $("time").text(),
  };
}
// rest of code
```

Comment: …or just initialise the property values in the object literal, instead of assigning them afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I was actually overwriting `newContent` variable. yet its a global variable.